# Haskell shake: special rule for building directories

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

Sometimes it is the case that to create a directory `mkdir` is not the right tool. It may be `git clone` or `rsync` or `mount`. So when we have a rule like this:

```
needDir dirs = filterM ((fmap not) . doesDirectoryExist) dirs >>= need

rules = do {
  "project" </> "tool" %> \out -> do {
    needDir [takeDirectory out];
    cmd "make -C" [takeDirectory out];
    }

  "project" %> \out -> cmd "git clone a.url.to/repo.git" [out]
  }
```

As one might expect the `"project" </> "tool"` creates the directory `project` before anything else and `git clone` isn't even run. Is there a way to go around this?

I suspect a new `Rule` is due here but I the docs were minimal and the code too confusing for me to come up with a working solution.

Comment: This issue is also being discussed at https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/430 (and the conclusions will be copied as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of directories as containers for files. They exist or don't pretty randomly, but if they have files, they must exist. In particular, you can't depend on a directory with `need` or write a rule to create a directory. Directories are created as needed - the rule for `project/tool.txt` will create the `project` directory if necessary.

If you want to depend on a `git clone` having being performed, depend on a particular checked-out file instead (e.g. `README.md`), with the rule to create it being `git clone`. If you want to ensure a `make` was run, depend on a file that `make` produces.

It is possible to define directory-aware rules, see [this discussion](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/430#issuecomment-196054985), but there are lots of caveats so it's not the recommended approach or supported by default.